# What is the best method to store a list of usernames against IP addresses in SQLite?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I need to log the usernames that a given hostname has used to connect to our chat application.

The database table has 2 columns `hostname` and `username`.

Example:

```
hostname  | username
---------------------------
127.0.0.1 | ben bill james rob
127.0.0.2 | bob sarah
127.0.0.3 | emma jessica xaria
```

In my Ruby code I will be calling for example `add_to_username_tracker(hostname,username)` I then need code to determine whether the IP address is present, and if so, fetch the current results, check whether the new username is present (if present then ignore) or add it and alphabetize.

What is the best method to do this? Can this be accomplished in SQLite only or does it require the Ruby to do it?

I am using `sqlite3` Gem.

Comment: Your question isn't well defined and is too broad. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

From the database point of view, your table needs to look more like this.

```
create table host_users (
  hostname varchar(20) not null, 
  username varchar(20) not null, 
  primary key (hostname, username)
);
```

> In my Ruby code I will be calling for example
>   add_to_username_tracker(hostname,username) I then need code to
>   determine whether the IP address is present, and if so, fetch the
>   current results, check whether the new username is present (if present
>   then ignore) or add it and alphabetize.

No, no, no. Just insert into the table, and trap the error if the insert violates the UNIQUE constraint.

```
insert into host_users values ('127.0.0.1', 'bob');
insert into host_users values ('127.0.0.1', 'bob');
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: host_users.hostname, host_users.username
```

This takes only *one* SQL statement.  You have to trap errors anyway. There's a lot that can go wrong besides violating a UNIQUE constraint.

To concatenate usernames into one row per hostname, use GROUP_CONCAT().

```
select hostname, group_concat(username) 
from host_users 
group by hostname;
```